# How does TemplateRef and ViewContainer differ in Angular 2

Tags: angular, templates, angular2-template

From my understanding of docs and few sample code, I realize that ViewContainer is something that holds a templateRef, while templateRef in itself holds the HTML. But I would like to know a further explanation:

I have questions like :

1. What each one of them exactly does.
2. How often do we find each one of    them in a layout. Is each of
   them associated with every single node    on my HTML.
3. Has it something to do with routing as well

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
Template Ref                            ViewContainerRef
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------     
Represents an Embedded Template         It is a continaer in which templates in
                                        which one or more Views can be attached

Used for creating a custom structural   Wrapper for holding the view
directive                               created using TemplateRef

Two ways to access                      Can attach views in 2 ways
   - using * infront                         - using createComponent()
   - using as a property binding             - using createEmbeddedView()
```

To answer your second question,

- We don't have a practice of creating structural directives.
- So, mostly we will not use it often.
- However, the structural directives which we use `ngIf, ngSwitch, ngFor` are creating using these classes.

Comment: U said ViewContainerRef attaches views by createComponent. Does it mean the template for every component is wrapped  in ViewContainer too.

Comment: i didnt get your question

Comment: A component has its own template provided within @Component decorator. Is this template also wrapped using ViewContainerRef.